# Mysql, php - one time password

Tags: passwords

I need to limit the access to a website and I want to send an individual passwort to each user that is valid only one time. The available OTP-solutions that I've found don't do the job. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do, but I use some light in-memory datastore like [redis](https://redis.io/) which generate a key(userid)-value(one time password) pair. Now you can send it via email/sms or any other channel. After the password is consumed successfully you can invalidate (or set an expiry time, could be done at redis).

If you don't want to do have a separate datastore, you can use mysql to store one time passwords for you.